# How can I edit document like doc,PDF in my browser?

Tags: python-3.x, angular, flask, openoffice.org, openoffice-base

**I have a client and he wants to open the document in browser. Edit the document and save it back to database or NextCloud. I am using angular as front-end technology and python flask as back-end . I have doubt whether it is possible or not and I am going through open office documentation to see whether it is possible to do this or not.**

Thanks in Advance!!!